pills alarm app support (IoT camera device over pills taken calendar keeps track of pills taken and sends "take pill and register it" alarms on time)
This post is about the support via smartphone alarms for medication taking and related hardware apps such as IoT pills taken calendar watcher camera device and possible smartwatch device.
Suppose you had to take medication, and needed to keep track of when you took it because before taking it or after taking it you could not remember if you took it.
This post is about the request for support for medication taking.
On a smartphone, it makes sense to have more than one alarm application (each one with it's own features and functionality, and catering.
For instance, one alarm application might cater to generic reminders and events, while another might cater to reminding and recording of medication taken. And the medication taken could be recorded on a special smartwatch with a button, that connected to Android when the phone was not charging to have this information entered into the phone automatically via WiFi connection.
It makes sense to have one alarm application just for pills.
It would, be, useful, to have an alarm that can be rescheduled.
Consider the arrangement where one person has n pills to take each day, and keeps boxes of pills in the kitchen, and, to remember whether the pills were taken each day and keep track of the regularity with which the pills were taken, the person keeps a paper calendar in the kitchen where a line appears for each day of the month on the calendar where the user puts a cross for each pill on the calendar on the column for each pill. Thus, days are rows, and pills (to be taken / to take) are columns.
Suppose above the calendar we place an IoT camera with optical character recognition which recognizes number of pills (number of columns) and crosses put on the calendar.
This IoT device knows the timing of each pill to be taken (this is programmed via an app on the smartphone that connects to the IoT device which learns the prescription details), and when the time comes, if the pill is not taken (because a cross does not appear on the calendar), the IoT device (which scans the calendar continuously) opens a special alarm application on the phone which tells the user to take the pill (and jot it down on the calendar by placing a cross on the pill's column).
Now consider that the app must also cater to the following undesired situations:
For instance you might be in a car, and your medication might be at home, but, the medication taken, might have alarms, which might be over one pill of one kind in the morning and one of another kind in the afternoon. The timing of such pills taken might allow for some flexibility, as long as one is taken in the morning and one in the afternoon.
If you are in the car, and it is afternoon, you need to reschedule the alarm for the second pill for when the car gets home (because you might not have taken the box of pills in the car and might have left the entire box of pills at home).
You can do this on your smartphone.
.
Here is another scenario the app must cater to:
The person could take a pill and forget to put the cross on the calendar. In this case, the alarm would go off, but, upon receiving the alarm, the person would remember that they took the pill but did not put a cross, and, simply put a cross on the calendar without taking another double pill (to fulfill the calendar, camera, and alarm app's expectations).
In this case, if the user was in a car and the pills were at home, the user could simply notify to the alarm "pill taken but need to record on calendar", where the calendar is at home, and simply click on the button for the referral of the jot down pill taken, for the alarm to remind user later to "jot down pill taken on calendar" at a later time (and the user can specify the time). The user may then specify the time they expect to be home on such an alarm. The user may also be on the street, in the middle of something, and recall that they took the pill but did not write it down. To avoid taking the pill twice, in this case, they can simply activate a " jot down on calendar" alarm referral to be activated when they return back home (and activate the time), overriding the "take pill because cross not present in calendar" alarm.
.
Who is willing to implement such a system.
Several self medicating people at home would benefit from such a system.
Who is willing to implement it?
Where can I find it?
Thanks.

